# Main content overflowing on sidebar when scrolled, using stickybits for sticking the sidebar

Tags: html, css

I am using stickybits(https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits) to stick my sidebar_content div(an inline-block) when scrolled. On scroll, my main_content div(also an inline-block) goes behind the sidebar_content and this is the case only in IE. It works perfectly fine on Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge and Safari. According to the documentation,

> Because Stickybits is minimal, when position: sticky is not supported Stickybits will use position: fixed which is relative to the browser window. If the StickyBits parent element has a height recognized by the browser, Stickybits will take care of the sticky top and sticky bottom invocation. If the parent's height is not recognized by the browser there will be issues.

I know that IE doesn't support `position: sticky`. I have tried `overflow: hidden;` on the body and various other things but it just doesn't seem to work. This is what I have so far:

```css
/* Main container that contains both main_content and sidebar_content */
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
    display: block;
}
.main_content {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 60%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.sidebar_content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 5%;
    max-width: 30%;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stickybits/3.7.2/stickybits.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar_content">
    This is my sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main_content">
    This is my main content
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well, perhaps in a CodePen.

Comment: @MistaPrime The HTML is quite simple actually. 2 inline blocks in the `container`. My issue only arises when I scroll, the `main_content` overlaps with the `sidebar_content`.

Comment: try position fixed or absolute and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use position: fixed targeting only IE?

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .ie10up {
        .sidebar_content {position: fixed;}

        .main_content {position: absolute; left: 30%; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a CodePen, but there could be a few things going on here:

- [There are issues with changing heights in IE11](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits/issues/548). Try explicitly setting the css height on your container div.
- Instead of using `vertical-align: top;` in your css, try setting the [vertical layout position](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits#vertical-layout-position) in your JS implementation of stickybits.

Answer (score 0):

Because IE doesn't support it position: sticky, So IE USES it position:fixed, So there is no element support to the left of main_content.  stickybits Provided in IE .js-is-sticky ,You can use this className to fix the location error

chrome
[image]

IE[image]

```
 .sidebar_content.js-is-sticky + .main_content{
        margin-left: 216px;
    }
```

```js
stickybits('.sidebar_content')
```

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
    display: block;
}
.main_content {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 60%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.sidebar_content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 5%;
    max-width: 30%;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.sidebar_content.js-is-sticky + .main_content{
    margin-left: 216px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stickybits/3.7.2/stickybits.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar_content">
    <pre>
      This is my sidebar
      This is my sidebar
      This is my sidebar
      This is my sidebar
      This is my sidebar
      This is my sidebar
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div class="main_content">
    <pre>
      
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    This is my main content
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but the overlapping still takes place. I have changed values for `margin-left` but I don't see any change.

Comment: @AlyssaAlex The point is this `.sidebar_content.js-is-sticky + .main_content{
    margin-left: 216px;
}·`  Open this in IE http://jsrun.pro/BBWKp

Comment: That works on IE, true. But it doesn't work for my case even though the structuring is the same. I have dynamic data, do you think that could be the reason?

Comment: If I have gotten it correctly, `margin-left: 216px;` will be applied to the main content after the sidebar becomes sticky, right? Because it looks like for me it has no effect.

Comment: @AlyssaAlex Yes, IE has an.js-is-sticky className,Other browsers don't.

Comment: Is there an alternative for `margin-left` ? :(

Comment: @AlyssaAlex none, You just have to understand why it overlaps to know that this is the only way to do it. You can also wrap a layer of DOM in the sidebar,Set the fixed width.

Comment: "You can also wrap a layer of DOM in the sidebar,Set the fixed width" Could you expand on that please?

Comment: @AlyssaAlex sorry, I tried it, but sticky lose efficacy, The 'sticky. Js' example has no interference with the adjacent DOM.